# If i select check bok how can i get value attributes 0,1 in customer controller

Tags: angularjs

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="detailcheckbok"  ng-model="checkboxModel_01"   ng-checked="true"  value="0"/> 
    Manual 
</label> 
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="detailcheckbok"   ng-model="checkboxModel_02" value="1"/> 
    Auto 
</label>  </div>

app.controller("customer", function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog) {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

by doing `ng-model="checkboxModel_01"`, you actually bind your checkbox to `$scope.checkboxModel_01`.

if you add a function that you call from your template, you will be able to see it :

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="detailcheckbok"  ng-model="checkboxModel_01" /> 
    Manual 
</label> 
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="detailcheckbok"   ng-model="checkboxModel_02"/> 
    Auto 
</label> 
<button ng-click="clickMe();"> Click me </button>


app.controller("customer", function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.clickMe = function() {
         alert("checkbox model 01: " + $scope.checkboxModel_01);
    };
});
```

Also :

- You should not use ng-model with ng-checked. They are not compatible. If you want to initialize your checkboxes, you should use `$scope.checkboxModel_01 = true;` inside your controller.
- The value behind a checkbox is a boolean (true / false), not 0 / 1 like you could have in c / sql / ...